# Fast way to sort a model by count of child's child

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I currently have the following models: MinorCategory > Product > Review
On a view, I show the 12 MinorCategories that have the most reviews. This view is very slow to respond, and I think it is a problem with how I do the query.

Here is my current code:

```
class MinorCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :reviews, through: :products
  ...
  def count_reviews
    self.reviews.count
  end
  ...
end
```

---

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product, touch: true
  ...
end
```

---

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  @categories = MinorCategory.all.sort_by(&:count_reviews).reverse.take(12)
end
```

---

So that is basically it. In the view itself I go through each @categories and display a few things, but the query in the controller is what seems to be slow. From SkyLight:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "reviews" INNER JOIN "products" ON "reviews"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "products"."minor_category_id" = ?   ... avg 472ms

I am not good with sql or active record, and still pretty new to Ruby on Rails. I've spent a couple hours trying other methods, but I can not get them to work so I thought I would check here.

Thank you in advance to anybody that has a moment.

Answer (score 1):

You need some basic SQL knowledge to better understand how database queries work, and how to take advantage of a DBMS. Using `ActiveRecord` is not an excuse to not learn some SQL.

That said, your query is very inefficient because you don't use the power of the database at all. It's a waste of resources both on the Ruby environment and on the database environment.

The only database query is

```
MinorCategory.all
```

which extracts all the records. This is insanely expensive, especially if you have  a large number of categories.

Moreover, `self.reviews.count` is largely inefficient because it is affected by the [N+1 query issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue).

Last but not least, the sorting and limiting is made in the Ruby environment, whereas you should really do it in the database.

You can easily obtain a more efficient query by taking advantage of the database computation capabilities. You will need to join the two tables together. The query should look like:

```
SELECT
    minor_categories.*, COUNT(reviews.id) AS reviews_count
FROM
    "minor_categories" INNER JOIN "reviews" ON "reviews"."minor_category_id" = "minor_categories"."id"
GROUP BY
    minor_categories.id
ORDER BY
    reviews_count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

which in ActiveRecord translates as

```
categories = MinorCategory.select('minor_categories.*, COUNT(reviews.id) AS reviews_count').joins(:reviews).order('reviews_count DESC').group('minor_categories.id').limit(10)
```

You can access a single category count by using `reviews_count`

```
# take a category 
category = categories[0]
category.reviews_count
```

Another approach that doesn't require a JOIN would be to cache the counter in the category table.